# How to create a fun puzzle?

Tags: puzzle-creation

There are some questions that marked off-topic or down-voted. I think there must be a place for whom try to create attractive or challenging puzzles in puzzling. So this topic came up.

---

**Question from experienced people in puzzle creation:**

Please post a brief explanation about

- *What are your experiences in creating puzzles?*
- *How do you often begin creating the brainstorm of your puzzle?*
- *What features would make a puzzle or riddle more attractive?*

PS. the answer with most up-votes will chose as correct answer. feel free to edit question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest and fastest way to create a puzzle is try to solve more and more puzzles. Then you will learn where to start and how to lead reader's minds. Reading more puzzles and their answers will make new ideas in your mind, too.

The other trick that I've learned recently is that *Don't just simply ask your question*. Make a story and place your question somewhere in your story. This is very important! It will be a huge advantage.